# Sending Image in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to send an image between two client/server in Adobe AIR, is there a way to do that, and if there is then how?

Comment: How do you access the image? via fileReference or it is a class object ?

Comment: You can use Socket or URLRequest + URLLoader to send img Bytes .

Comment: I access it via FileReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the Image to a byte array and send it via AMF.

If the server is php:
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/AMF_Flash_Remoting_with_Zend_and_CI

If the server is another Adobe Air app, then it should handle AMF out of the box.

Heres another tutorial:

http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/06/09/airserver-handling-both-sockets-websockets-in-adobe-air/